# PYTHON: What is the fastest way of checking and editing an element in a structured array if it exists?

Tags: python, numpy, structured-array

I have some issues with very large data sets. I need to find a solid and fast way to find/replace entries in my structured array. I am looking for an solution without looping of all entries. I know there are fast solutions for C but I do not know how to approach in python for that. I am also wonder if there is a numpy function for that very purpose!

I am using Python 2.7.13 and numpy 1.12.1!

**TASK:**
Set all positions of the orphans to the positions of the `data_centrals` by finding the **haloid** of the *orphan* from `data_orphan` in the list of the *centrals* in `data_centrals`.

```
import numpy as np

data =  Structured array:
    class:  ndarray
    shape:  (189258912,)

dt = [('hostid', '<u8'), ('z_pos', '<f8'), ('x_pos', '<f8'),
     ('y_pos', '<f8'), ('haloid', '<u8'), ('orphan', 'i1')]
```

EDITED: **A subsamples of data with 200 objects can be downloaded** [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/937txfa2zpvgiog/data.txt?dl=0)! It structure is given by *dt*: first column--> *hostid*, second --> *z_pos*, etc. It can be copy/pasted as it is into a python shell or script ...

Below you can find the code for setting the positions.

QUESTION: **Is there are smart way of searching for the haloids and setting the positions without looping over all entries of `data_orphan`?**

```
data_centrals=data[np.where(data['haloid']==data['hostid'])] # (111958237,)

data_orphans=data[np.where(data['orphan']==2)]               # (61870681,)

a=0
while a<len(data_orphans):

    #check where in data_centrals the haloid of the orphan can be found
    position=np.where(data_centrals['haloid']==data_orphans['haloid'][a])

    #find the position of data_orphan['haloid'][a] in data
    position_data=np.where(data['hostid']==data_orphans['hostid'][a])

    #set the positions
    data['x_pos'][int(position_data[0])]=data_centrals['x_pos'][int(position[0])]        
    data['y_pos'][int(position_data[0])]=data_centrals['y_pos'][int(position[0])]       
    data['z_pos'][int(position_data[0])]=data_centrals['z_pos'][int(position[0])]

    a+=1
```

Comment: I suspect `np.in1d` could be used for the first `position` calc, outside of loop.

Comment: What's the typical length of `data_orphans`, and `data_centrals` relative to `data`.

Comment: If you hang on to `np.where(data['orphan']==2)`, you shouldn't have to perform the 2nd `position_data` `where`.

Comment: I could put my comments into an answer, but I'd have to construct a top problem to illustrate and test them.  That's something that you should do for us.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, thanks for your comments. The np.in1d-advise was very useful, I do know now that every orphan has its central. However, I still need to set the position of the orphan to that of the central ...

Comment: What do you mean with: _to construct a top problem to illustrate and test them. That's something that you should do for us._ What can I do your the community?

Comment: Sorry, a type.  I meant write a `toy problem`.   The SO help has something about a MVCe - minimal, verifiable, concrete example.  Look at the answers to other questions.  Most involve working code with real examples.

Comment: @hpaulj: I enclosed a link with a subsample of 200 objects, ready to copy and paste ... is this ok to work with?

Answer (score 1):

If your data structure is a plain, unordered list or array then the answer is no. It will take linear time O(n) to find a specific element. If the list/array is ordered you can do a binary search in O(lg n) time. You may also consider alternative data structures like a balanced BST or python dictionary with better search times, but it depends on the structure of your data if such an approach is appropriate.